# Adding multiple rows of data from one sheet to another using App Script

Tags: google-sheets, invoice

I’m working on creating an invoice generator in Google Sheets using App Script. How it works is that after filling in all necessary info in the google sheet and clicking on a printer icon, the script generates a PDF-formatted invoice and emails it, transfers necessary info into Task History, which is another sheet, and clears selected fields for you to create another invoice easily. The only issue I’m battling with is copying over multiple rows of data from Date, Project Name, Description of work, Language, Type, Dept, Frequency, Area, Region, Hours, Rate (C26~N49) in new rows in another sheet (Task History). The script I wrote only copies over the first row of data (C25:N25). I would like data to pile up each time I generate an invoice so new data has to be entered in new row(s). Also, I would like the script to ignore rows that have no value in them. I attached files for your reference.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XdUvCdjcO8YcLK7WNnAUCwyGFFBXTEjGjfP7MCMwgOE/edit Invoice generator app script

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wl9ZKKUUKeSCh9ELNl0O-WvqKpmZox5LdsTvY-lXrVU/edit#gid=654851390
(Practice) Request Management

Your help would be much appreciated!

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/artSD.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyNQe.png)

Here's a part of the script that needs to be fixed

```
//Transcribes the invoice details to the Task History sheet
function taskmakeHistory() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Invoice");
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Task History");
 
  //insert new line and copy formatting to it
 
  destSheet.insertRowAfter(4); //Inserts a row before populating it
  var source_range = destSheet.getRange("A4:O4");//the next three lines copy a preformatted line and paste it underneath
  var target_range = destSheet.getRange("A5:O5");
  source_range.copyTo(target_range);
 
  //Define all the origin cells, dest cells and transcribe
  var invoiceNum = destSheet.getRange("A5").setValue(sheet.getRange("N8").getValue());
  var invoiceDate = destSheet.getRange("B5").setValue(sheet.getRange("N5").getValue());
  var invoicetaskcompletiondate = destSheet.getRange("C5").setValue(sheet.getRange("C25:C49").getValues());
  var projectname = destSheet.getRange("F5").setValue(sheet.getRange("D25:D49").getValues());
  var language = destSheet.getRange("G5").setValue(sheet.getRange("G25:G49").getValues());
  var type = destSheet.getRange("H5").setValue(sheet.getRange("H25:H49").getValues());
  var dept = destSheet.getRange("I5").setValue(sheet.getRange("I25:I49").getValues());
  var frequency = destSheet.getRange("J5").setValue(sheet.getRange("J25:J49").getValues());
  var area = destSheet.getRange("K5").setValue(sheet.getRange("K25:K49").getValues());
  var region = destSheet.getRange("L5").setValue(sheet.getRange("L25:L49").getValues());
  var hours = destSheet.getRange("M5").setValue(sheet.getRange("M25:M49").getValues());
  var rate = destSheet.getRange("N5").setValue(sheet.getRange("N25:N49").getValues());
}
```